# Filter listview from fields in attached edit form

Tags: 2010, list-view, filter, browser-enabled-form

I have a browser enabled InfoPath edit form with a list view web-part placed underneath the form. The form and the view represent two different lists. I know OOB they can be connected using only one field.

Is it possible to filter the list view using multiple fields from the form concurrently using web-parts, SPD, JS, or any other method? I'm trying to stay away from SP list filters if possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was way easier than I thought. Use SP designer to open up the page in edit mode, select "Add Connection" from the "Options" tab and proceed to connect the fields from the form to the fields in the view that you would like to filter on.